# How to fix scratched glass

Tags: windshield, repair, diy

Recently I discovered that I have a small but a bit deep scratch on a rear door glass ( I have hatchback ). I am not sure how it happened but it is there now and it bugs me quite a bit.

Can I fix it myself via some sort of a repair kit? Or do I need to bring my car to repair shop? At this point I can't afford to replace the glass and would like to fix it myself.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you can try regular buffing/polishing techniques similar to what you would do with paint.

However those can only be done on the outside of the rear window because you will damage your defroster element if the scratch is on the inside of the vehicle.

Another DIY trick is to use clear nail polish to fill the scratch.

Answer (score 1):

There are various DIY solutions available, which will probably be appropriate for a side or rear window (for a front windscreen regulations are usually quite specific) and they apply a quick setting transparent gel.

Your local Halfords or other car maintenance shop should stock this sort of thing. Vendors such as Autoglass can also do quick repairs.